# Write commands in cmd with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, nrf51, segger-jlink

I'm now starting to develop little programs using VB.net.

I started with an App Windows Form. I would like to know some information about my microcontroller (such as MAC ADDRESS etc.). To know this information, I have to access its registers using Segger J-Link and to use a software called J-Link commander. To read registers I have to open jlinkCommander.exe and specify some parameters (device, target, speed in kHz, etc.) writing some command lines.

[image]

How can I open JlinkCommander.exe and put all these parameters just pushing a button in Windows form?

Comment: Do you mean to run an application with parameters?

Comment: A good place to start would be the [product manual](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/UM08001).

Comment: Page 130: *The J-LinkARM.dll is a standard Windows DLL typically used from C or C++, but also Visual
Basic or Delphi projects. It makes the entire functionality of the J-Link / J-Trace available
through the exported functions. The functionality includes things such as halting/stepping
the ARM core, reading/writing CPU and ICE registers and reading/writing memory. Therefore,
it can be used in any kind of application accessing a CPU core.*

Comment: [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Using [Process.StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe(v=vs.110).aspx) to make more arguments, and then you can run it using `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`

Comment: @djv 's suggestion is probably the best way to go, plugging in directly to your application is safer and easier to debug than trying to process.start and pass over commands.